# Прелоадинг коллекции audio (mp3) файлов

Tags: аудио, javascript

MSIE11, HTML5, JavaScript, new Audio()

Проблема: прелоадинг(-ируютя) только 123 файла?!

Условия упрощены до следующего состояния:

- в папке 350 одинаковых (.mp3 17Кб) файлов;
- имена файлов - номера от 1 до 350;

.

```
function collection(){  
    for(var i=1;i<=350;i++){MIM_BFR[i]=new Audio()  
        MIM_BFR[i].setAttribute('preload','auto')

        MIM_BFR[i].addEventListener('loadeddata',MIM_Yes)  
        MIM_BFR[i].addEventListener('error',MIM_No)

        MIM_BFR[i].setAttribute('autobuffer',true)  
        MIM_BFR[i].setAttribute('type','audio/mpeg')   
        MIM_BFR[i].src=mim_dir+i+'.mp3'
    }
}
```

Т.е. в `MIM_Yes()` фиксируются только 123 захода; всё остальное улетает в `MIM_No()`:

- номера загруженных файлов 'случайные' в [1-350]; их, кстати, можно и упорядочить (1-->123), если new `Audio()` совершать с интервалом в несколько миллисекунд;
- попытка ввести число повторов при 'error' ничего нового  не даёт;
- замена 'loadeddata' на 'canplaythrough' также ничего нового  не даёт;
- употребление тега `audio(HTML5)` вместо `new Audio()(JavaScript)` - эффект тот же.

Вопрос: как объехать это ограничение - 123?  
(Не хочется склеивать файлы (хотя папок со звуками, конечно, значительно меньше, чем 123) и считать интервалы!)

Comment: Что говорят вкладка network или [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?
Может быть файлов действительно нет :) Попробуйте включать autobuffer после указания ссылки на файл

Comment: А что происходит в сети (Dev tools > Network)? Возможно, сервер не отдает файлы, ограничивая число параллельных соединений. Возможно, пока 124-ый файл начнет буффериться, у него наступает таймаут.